# Undefined property, PDO Exception Erros

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, undefined

I have tried adding `PDO::PARAM_STR` and `$stmt->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_INT);`
neither of those have worked.

I get the following errors:

> Notice: Undefined property:
>   Foundationphp\Sessions\AutoLogin::$sess_ukey in .... /AutoLogin.php on
>   line 107
>
> Notice: Undefined property:
>   Foundationphp\Sessions\AutoLogin::$col_ukey in .../AutoLogin.php on
>   line 191
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' in
>   ...../AutoLogin.php on line 195
>
> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'FROM users WHERE username = 'david'' at line 1 in
>   ..../AutoLogin.php on line 195

The code is as follows:

```
     <?php
    namespace Foundationphp\Sessions;

    class AutoLogin
    {
    use PersistentProperties;

    /**
     * @var \PDO Database connection
     */
    protected $db;

    /**
     * @var int Position at which user key is inserted in single-use token
     */
    protected $token_index;

    /**
     * @var int Number of days the autologin cookie remains valid
     */
    protected $lifetimeDays = 30;

    /**
     * @var int Unix timestamp for when the cookie expires
     */
    protected $expiry;

    /**
     * @var string Path to be set in the autologin cookie
     */
    protected $cookiePath = '/persistent';

    /**
     * @var string Domain for autologin cookie
     */
    protected $domain = '';

    /**
     * @var null Whether cookie should be sent only over a secure connection
     */
    protected $secure = null;

    /**
     * @var bool Whether cookie should be accessible only through HTTP protocol
     */
    protected $httponly = true;


    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * Requires a PDO connection to the database where the user's credentials,
     * session data, and autologin details are stored.
     *
     * @param \PDO $db Datatbase connection
     * @param int $token_index Position at which user key is to be inserted in token
     */
    public function __construct(\PDO $db, $token_index = 0)
    {
        $this->db = $db;
        if ($this->db->getAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE) !== \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION) {
            $this->db->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        }
        $this->token_index = ($token_index <= 31) ? $token_index : 31;
        $this->expiry = time() + ($this->lifetimeDays * 60 * 60 * 24);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a persistent login for the user
     *
     * The login process gets the user's unique key (an 8-digit
     * hexadecimal string), and stores it with a random 32-digit
     * string. Both values are merged and appended to the
     * username to create a single-use token that's stored as a
     * cookie in the user's browser.
     */
    public function persistentLogin()
    {
        // Get the user's ID
        if ($_SESSION[$this->sess_ukey] = $this->getUserKey()) {
            $this->getExistingData();
            // Generate a random 32-digit hexadecimal token
            $token = $this->generateToken();
            // Store the token and user's ID in the database
            $this->storeToken($token);
            // Store the single-use token as a cookie in the user's browser
            $this->setCookie($token);
            $_SESSION[$this->sess_persist] = true;
            unset($_SESSION[$this->cookie]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Check if a valid persistent cookie has been presented
     *
     * If the cookie exists, the user's unique key is retrieved
     * from the database and removed from the single-use token.
     * Before checking for a matching pair, expired tokens are
     * deleted from the database. If the token is valid, data from
     * the stored session is retrieved and added to the current
     * session.
     */
    public function checkCredentials()
    {
        // Do nothing if the cookie doesn't exist
        if (isset($_COOKIE[$this->cookie])) {
            if ($storedToken = $this->parseCookie()) {
                // Delete expired tokens before checking the current one
                $this->clearOld();
                // Log in the user if the token hasn't been used
                if ($this->checkCookieToken($storedToken, false)) {
                    // Log in the user
                    $this->cookieLogin($storedToken);
                    // Generate and store a fresh single-use token
                    $newToken = $this->generateToken();
                    $this->storeToken($newToken);
                    $this->setCookie($newToken);
                } elseif ($this->checkCookieToken($storedToken, true)) {
                    // If the token has already been used, suspect an attack,
                    // delete all tokens associated with the user key,
                    // and invalidate the current session.
                    $this->deleteAll();
                    $_SESSION = [];
                    $params = session_get_cookie_params();
                    setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 86400, $params['path'], $params['domain'],
                        $params['secure'], $params['httponly']);
                    session_destroy();
                    // Invalidate the autologin cookie
                    setcookie($this->cookie, '', time() - 86400, $this->cookiePath,
                        $this->domain, $this->secure, $this->httponly);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Logs out the user from all sessions or just the current one
     *
     * @param bool $all True if all sessions are to be deleted
     */
    public function logout($all = true)
    {
        if ($all) {
            $this->deleteAll();
        } else {
            $token = $this->parseCookie();
            $sql = "UPDATE $this->table_autologin SET $this->col_used = 1
                    WHERE $this->col_token = :token";
            $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindParam(':token', $token);
            $stmt->execute();
        }
        setcookie($this->cookie, '', time() - 86400, $this->cookiePath,
            $this->domain, $this->secure, $this->httponly);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves the user's ID from the users table
     *
     * @return string User's ID
     */
    protected function getUserKey()
    {
        $sql = "SELECT $this->col_ukey FROM $this->table_users
                WHERE $this->col_name = :username";
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(':username', $_SESSION[$this->sess_uname], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt->fetchColumn();
    }


    /**
     * Retrieve the user's data from the most recent session
     */
    protected function getExistingData()
    {
        $sql = "SELECT $this->col_data FROM $this->table_autologin
                WHERE $this->col_ukey = :key
                ORDER BY $this->col_created DESC";
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(':key', $_SESSION[$this->sess_ukey]);
        $stmt->execute();
        // Get the most recent result
        if ($data = $stmt->fetchColumn()) {
            // Populate the $_SESSION superglobal array
            session_decode($data);
        }
        // Release the database connection for other queries
        $stmt->closeCursor();
    }

    /**
     * Generates a random 32-character string for the single-use token
     *
     * @return string 32-character hexadecimal string
     */
    protected function generateToken()
    {
        return bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16));
    }

    /**
     * Stores the user's ID and single-use token in the database
     *
     * @param string $token 32-character hexadecimal string
     */
    protected function storeToken($token)
    {
        try {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO $this->table_autologin
                    ($this->col_ukey, $this->col_token)
                    VALUES (:key, :token)";
            $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindParam(':key', $_SESSION[$this->sess_ukey]);
            $stmt->bindParam(':token', $token);
            $stmt->execute();
        } catch (\PDOException $e) {
            if ($this->db->inTransaction()) {
                $this->db->rollBack();
            }
            throw $e;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Creates and stores autologin cookie in user's browser
     *
     * @param string $token 32-character single-use token
     */
    protected function setCookie($token)
    {
        $merged = str_split($token);
        array_splice($merged, hexdec($merged[$this->token_index]), 0, $_SESSION[$this->sess_ukey]);
        $merged = implode('', $merged);

        $token = $_SESSION[$this->sess_uname] .'|' . $merged;
        setcookie($this->cookie, $token, $this->expiry,
            $this->cookiePath, $this->domain, $this->secure,
            $this->httponly);
    }

    /**
     * Removes the user_key from the cookie token
     *
     * @return array|bool Array containing the username and token, or false
     */
    protected function parseCookie()
    {
        // Separate the username and submitted token
        $parts = explode('|', $_COOKIE[$this->cookie]);
        $_SESSION[$this->sess_uname] = $parts[0];
        $token = $parts[1];

        // Proceed only if the username is valid
        if ($_SESSION[$this->sess_ukey] = $this->getUserKey()) {
            // Remove the user's ID from the submitted cookie token
            return str_replace($_SESSION[$this->sess_ukey], '', $token);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Deletes records older than the value set in the $lifetimeDays property
     */
    protected function clearOld()
    {
        $sql = "DELETE FROM $this->table_autologin
                WHERE DATE_ADD($this->col_created, INTERVAL :expiry DAY) < NOW()";
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(':expiry', $this->lifetimeDays);
        $stmt->execute();
    }

    /**
     * Checks whether the single-use token has already been used
     *
     * @param string $token 32-digit single-use token
     * @param bool $used
     * @return bool Depends on value of $used
     */
    protected function checkCookieToken($token, $used)
    {
        $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $this->table_autologin
                WHERE $this->col_ukey = :key AND $this->col_token = :token
                AND $this->col_used = :used";
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(':key', $_SESSION[$this->sess_ukey]);
        $stmt->bindParam(':token', $token);
        $stmt->bindParam(':used', $used, \PDO::PARAM_BOOL);
        $stmt->execute();
        if ($stmt->fetchColumn() > 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Delete all entries in autologin table related with the user's ID
     */
    protected function deleteAll()
    {
        $sql = "DELETE FROM $this->table_autologin WHERE $this->col_ukey = :key";
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(':key', $_SESSION[$this->sess_ukey]);
        $stmt->execute();
    }

    /**
     * Logs in the user if the single-use cookie is valid
     *
     * @param string $token 32-character single-use token
     */
    protected function cookieLogin($token)
    {
        try {
            $this->getExistingData($_SESSION[$this->sess_ukey]);

            $sql = "UPDATE $this->table_autologin SET $this->col_used = 1
                    WHERE $this->col_ukey = :key AND $this->col_token = :token";
            $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindParam(':key', $_SESSION[$this->sess_ukey]);
            $stmt->bindParam(':token', $token);
            $stmt->execute();

            session_regenerate_id(true);

            $_SESSION[$this->cookie] = true;
            unset($_SESSION[$this->sess_auth]);
            unset($_SESSION[$this->sess_revalid]);
            unset($_SESSION[$this->sess_persist]);
        } catch (\PDOException $e) {
            if ($this->db->inTransaction()) {
                $this->db->rollBack();
            }
            throw $e;
        }

    }

}
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

Because, you need to address PDO with a `\` mainly because there is no such class called `PDO` in YOUR application class namespace. What this does is it looks for the `PDO` class in the `\` namespace, which is where it is. You should do something like this now:

`$stmt->bindParam(':username', $username, \PDO::PARAM_INT);`

To stop having to do that again and again, you can do:

`use PDO;` after you define the `namespace` and before the `class` keyword.

Comment: Hassan thank you for the suggestion.  I am still getting errors of the same sort.

        namespace Foundationphp\Sessions;
        use: PDO;
       
    protected function getUserKey()
    {
        $sql = "SELECT $this->col_ukey FROM $this->table_users
                WHERE $this->col_name = :username";
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(':username',$username, \PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt->fetchColumn();
 }
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try the use keyword.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by keywords so I have not tried that yet.  :( new to php and trying to teach myself.

Comment: Just add `use PDO;` after `namespace` is defined.

Comment: I tried that still am getting errors.  Keeps saying stmt excute has errors and a few other things.  I can post the lines it says has errors if that would help.  Thank you for all your suggestions.  I'm honestly not sure where the issue is that's making it not work .  :(

Comment: Upload the entire file code, and put it on pastebin, and send me here. and also all the errors in pastebin.

Comment: Thank you , we don't have internet so I started over but I do have an issue with updating database. If I post code can you help with that?

Comment: @shutterfly Yes, but not in this question. Create a new one. And, tick this answer please.

Comment: Silly question how do I close this question I can not figure it out.  I tried answer but tells me I did not answer properly.  Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: @shutterfly You don't need to close this. You don't close questions. Tick the right answer here, that's all you need to do.